# Java - swap in the array

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I want to swap 2 values in an array...
This is my code:

```
    static void swap (Integer[] input, int i, int j) {

    /*
     * Assure indices are allright!
     */
    if (i < 0 || i >= input.length)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect i!");
    if (j < 0 || j >= input.length)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect j!");

    /*
     * (***) This method does not work... Why? (***)
     */
     input[i] ^= input[j];
     input[j] ^= input[i];
     input[i] ^= input[j];

    /*
     * This works...
     */
    /*int temp = input[j];
    input[j] = input[i];
    input[i] = temp;*/
}
```

Why does the method in the middle (***) not work???

Comment: How does it not work? What do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: You are setting `input[j] = input[i] - input[j];`, how would that ever give you the correct result for `input[j]`. If you meant to us `+=` it would be closer although I think your `input[i]` would still be incorrect.

Comment: Actually, I just tested this.  It works for me, except in the case where `i == j`.  What goes wrong for you when you try it?

Comment: It will fail for the special case i == j. You outsmarted yourself :)

Comment: Yeah, it was just the case i == j that ruins it all...

Comment: It would have been better if you'd actually mentioned that in the question; it seems like quite a few people have spent their time trying to understand what you're doing, and even testing it themselves.  Whereas it's absolutely obvious why everything turns to zero in the case  with `i == j`.

Comment: I have voted to close this.  I think it's irreparable.  If you don't mention in the question that it only fails if `i == j`, then you're really not providing the information required to reproduce the problem, which is one of the sub-reasons of the "off topic" close reason.  But if you change the question to say "why does the code not work if `i == j`" then you're really asking "why do I get zero if I subtract a number from itself"; which probably belongs on math.stackexchange.com - certainly not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a version of the [XOR Swap Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) which isn't a very effective optimization with a dynamic language like Java. Instead, I suggest that you try to [Write Dumb Code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/devinsight-1-139780.html); and you already have a working swap using a temporary variable (which seems like the best solution to me) so I guess I'll show you a correct xor swap... One final note, make sure to not try this if `i == j`...

```
if (i == j) {
    return;
}
input[i] ^= input[j];
input[j] ^= input[i];
input[i] ^= input[j];
```

If you try subtraction (or xor) when i equals j you will get zero.

Comment: There's nothing broken about this method at all - it's just different from the one that you know.  Sure, it's not a good way of swapping variables, but it's completely untrue to say "it doesn't work because it's a broken version of ...".  The method itself works fine, except if `i == j`.

Comment: @david edited to explain the way it is broken,instead of merely stating it.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed.  I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

It does work, at least sometimes. You should explain the problem better, with example input and output. Here's a working test:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public final class Swapper
{

  @Test
  public void testSwap()
  {
    Integer[] input = {1, 2, 3};
    swap(input, 0, 2);
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new Integer[]{3, 2, 1}, input);
  }

  @Test
  public void testNoop()
  {
    Integer[] input = {1, 2, 3};
    swap(input, 1, 1);
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}, input);
  }

  static void swap(Integer[] input, int i, int j)
  {
    if (i < 0 || i >= input.length)
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(Integer.toString(i));
    if (j < 0 || j >= input.length)
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(Integer.toString(j));
    input[i] = input[i] + input[j];
    input[j] = input[i] - input[j];
    input[i] = input[i] - input[j];
  }

}
```

As you've already discovered, when `i` and `j` are equal, your method will fail. It would be easy to fix that by checking that condition after validating the index ranges.

That said, this is a terrible way to swap elements, because of the way that Java works with primitive types like `int` and their `Object` counterparts, like `Integer`. You are creating a lot of `Integer` object instances, and that's likely to be a lot slower than using a local variable to hold an element in transit.

Comment: Are you sure that `testNoop` passes?

Comment: @DavidWallace It does not pass.